Error with Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential after downgrading .NET
Initially I wrote my program in .NET 8.0 and everything works fine.
I have an .NET application which use the MS Graph API to fetch emails.
Due to some requirements, I have to downgrade to .NET6.0.
After refactoring my code, I am able to run the the program but there is a problem with the authentication for Azure Identity.
I now get the error

An error occurred in Run: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Method not found: 'Void System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonObjectInfoValues1.set_ObjectCreator(System.Func1<!0>)'

Here is my ConfigurationService:
public abstract class TcConfigurationServices
{
    private static readonly string[] sScopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection tServices, IConfiguration tConfiguration)
    {
        // Bind configuration sections to POCO classes
        tServices.Configure<TcJiraOptions>(tConfiguration.GetSection("Jira"));
        tServices.Configure<TcAzureAdOptions>(tConfiguration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        
        //Console.WriteLine(tConfiguration.GetValue<string?>("Jira:ProjectKey"));
        
        // Add HttpClient for TcJiraService
        tServices.AddHttpClient<TcJiraService>();

        // Register GraphServiceClient with a factory method
        tServices.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(tServiceProvider =>
        {
            var aAzureOptions = tServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TcAzureAdOptions>>().Value;
            var aClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                aAzureOptions.TenantId,
                aAzureOptions.ClientId,
                aAzureOptions.ClientSecret);

            // Create an instance of GraphServiceClient with the ClientSecretCredential
            var aGraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(aClientSecretCredential, sScopes);

            return aGraphServiceClient;
        });

        tServices.AddSingleton<TcMailService>();

        // Add logging services
        tServices.AddLogging(tLoggingBuilder =>
        {
            tLoggingBuilder.ClearProviders(); // Clear existing providers
            tLoggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace); // Set the minimum log level to Trace
            tLoggingBuilder.AddNLog(); // Add NLog as the logging provider
            tLoggingBuilder.AddConsole(); // Add console logging
            tLoggingBuilder.AddDebug(); // Add debug logging
        });

        // Register the main application class
        tServices.AddTransient<TcApp>();

        tServices.AddSingleton(tResolver =>
            tResolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TcJiraOptions>>().Value);
        tServices.AddSingleton(tResolver =>
            tResolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TcAzureAdOptions>>().Value);
    }
}

I am not sure why it is not working. I suppose there is a problem with incorrect dependency for authentication?
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Core" Version="1.38.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.45.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.9" />
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.8" />
        <Content Include="Templates\*.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <None Remove="nlog.config" />
        <Content Include="nlog.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

There is something wrong with the package System.Text.Json maybe?

You say you are using .NET 8/6 but your dependencies in csproj are 9.x. Try to downgrade them to match your runtime version.

That was the problem, yes. I didn't know that the dependencies version in csproj is related with .NET version. Downgrading the versions of the packages worked.

Can you please post your sol as an answer.
